# JSON returns one field with ID and other field with full object, when both objects are same

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, rest, jackson-databind

I have a class like below.

```
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode
@Entity
@Table( name = "hires", indexes = { @Index( name = "idx_hire_date", columnList = "date DESC" ) }, uniqueConstraints = {
    @UniqueConstraint( columnNames = { "vehicle_id", "po_number" } ) } )
@DynamicUpdate
@JsonIdentityInfo( generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "id" )
public class Hire implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue( strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY )
int id;

@OneToOne( targetEntity = Driver.class, fetch = FetchType.EAGER )
@JoinColumn( name = "pass_payer", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = true )
Driver passPayer;

@OneToOne( targetEntity = Driver.class, fetch = FetchType.EAGER )
@JoinColumn( name = "driver_id", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = true )
Driver driver;
...
}
```

I get this object via a Rest endpoint.
The problem is when the field **passPayer** and **driver** objects are equal, in the returning JSON, the **driver** field contains only the ID (which is just an integer value) and **passPayer** field has all the object fields.

```
"passCost": 300.0,
        "passPayer": {
            "id": 9,
            "firstName": "XXXX",
            "lastName": "XXXXXX",
            "idNo": "000000000000"
        },
        "driver": 9,
        "driverSalary": xxxx.xx,
```

When these fields have different objects, both fields show full details like below.

```
"passCost": 300.0,
        "passPayer": {
            "id": 9,
            "firstName": "XXXX",
            "lastName": "XXXXXX",
            "idNo": "000000000000"
        },
        "driver": {
            "id": 4,
            "firstName": "YYYYYY",
            "lastName": "YYYYYYY",
            "idNo": "10101010101"
        },
        "driverSalary": 00000.00,
```

I need both objects to contain data (fields. [id, firstName, lastName, idNo]) whether they are equal or not.

***Any clue is appreciated!***

Comment: What data do you expect **driver** to hold in the first example, where only a number is provided?

Comment: @Koenigsberg 
Same fields as passPayer. 
Since the data type of both fields is Driver.class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is caused by `@JsonIdentityInfo( generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "id" )`, check the [docs](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.4/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonIdentityInfo.html). To cite :

> Annotation used for indicating that values of annotated type or
> property should be serializing so that instances either contain
> additional object identifier (in addition actual object properties),
> or as a reference that consists of an object id that refers to a full
> serialization.

Since both fields are referencing the same object, the second one is serialized as a reference to the first object.

In my experience, this annotation is mostly used to deal with circular references, so you can:

1. remove it, if your use case allows it(no circular references in object)
2. or you can use DTOs(which is the prefered approach anyway)

Comment: Yes, I have circular references. Will DTOs help to get rid of it also?

Comment: @NipunaPerera Depends on how you create the dto, you don't want circular reference in dto, unless you really can't help it. In it you only put the data which needs to be sent(or received) in the desired format.

Comment: Thanks. I could resolve the issue with DTO object. Thanks again!